# can I display custom javascript in streamlit web app

Tags: javascript, python, streamlit

I am working on a parking data app using Streamlit library in python 3.7, I want to display the availability of parking spots using custom JavaScript for visualization.
Is it possible to display HTML/javascript elements in streamlit web app

Comment: good luck. Come back when you get error message.

Comment: @furas I am asking it is possible, I don't seem to find anything about it in Streamlit documentation.

Comment: then check source code.

Comment: using Google `streamlit add html`I found [How to render already prepared html code with Streamlit?](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-render-already-prepared-html-code-with-streamlit/3387/3) which uses `st.markdown(html_string, unsafe_allow_html=True)`. It think you could use it to add HTML and JavaScript.  But in documentation I found [Create a Streamlit Component](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/streamlit_components.html) and maybe this can be more interesting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Digging in Google I found:

You can add HTML using

```
import streamlit as st

st.markdown(html_string, unsafe_allow_html=True)
```

but this can't add JavaScript.

Forum: [How to render already prepared html code with Streamlit?](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/how-to-render-already-prepared-html-code-with-streamlit/3387/2)

---

You can add HTML and JavaScript using

```
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

components.html(html_string)
```

but this puts it in `<iframe>`

Doc: [Components API reference](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/develop_streamlit_components.html)

---

Minimal working example

```
import streamlit as st
import streamlit.components.v1 as components

html_string = '''
<h1>HTML string in RED</h1>

<script language="javascript">
  document.querySelector("h1").style.color = "red";
  console.log("Streamlit runs JavaScript");
  alert("Streamlit runs JavaScript");
</script>
'''

components.html(html_string)  # JavaScript works

st.markdown(html_string, unsafe_allow_html=True)  # JavaScript doesn't work
```

---

To put directly HTML with JavaScript you would need to build `Component`
but it seems more complex method which may need code in `TypeScript`.

See videos in doc: [Create a Streamlit Component](https://docs.streamlit.io/en/stable/streamlit_components.html)

Comment: even those custom components [get rendered in an iframe](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/components/components-api): "built out of HTML and any other web tech you like (JavaScript, React, Vue, etc.), and **gets rendered in Streamlit apps via an iframe tag**."